# jdbctemplate and db2 with ResultSetExtractor query is very slow

Tags: java, spring-boot, db2, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

From my springboot app , i am querying DB2. the query is quick on my sql client and on springboot 
it's taking ages, i am not doing any logic but just trying to print out.

I am using ResultSetExtractor and tried to set fetchSize to 500

```
jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(500);

while (resultSet.next()) {System.out.println(resultSet.getString("column_name")}
```

I am getting about 600000 rows from the database

and getting this error after a long wait

```
nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-4712, SQLSTATE=5U026,
```

any help is much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to show all of the exception (it is missing the reason code for the sqlcode -4712. Your query exceeded some resource-limit imposed by the Db2-server (and the reason code will show *which* kind of threshold was exceeded).  You say the Query is fast on the SQL-client (on your workstation?), but we cannot know if the query is identical from Spring Boot, or whether hostvariables were used, or whether the access plan is the same.   So you need to do more problem determination here.

Comment: Apart from the above remark, to do a row-by-row fetch of around 600,000 rows is hardly optimal. Depending on the reason you are pulling that number of rows, consider whether an export or unload action might be preferable.